# ggfority::autoplot residual plot is tiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I'm creating residual plots using `ggfortify::autoplot(aov_obj, which = 1, colour = ...)` in Rmarkdown.

However, the x axis on this plot was really condensed compared to the y axis, 
[image]

So I used `{r, fig.width = 20}` in my chunk. This spread out the size of x axis BUT reduced the size of the title and height.
[image]

(It might not look that way in this screenshot, but consider in the context of the 1st image. I want it to be that big)

Essentially, all I want to do is either

- Stretch out the x axis on the first image, without making reducing the size of the title or height or axis labels.
- Or make the second image larger in general

**Extra things I've tried so far**

- `fig.height`. This just makes the second image longer, but the titles still remain tiny and the width is still tiny no matter how large I set it.
- `out.height` and `out.width`. If used by themselves, makes the plot absolutely minuscule no matter how small/large these values are. If used in conjunction with `fig.width`, doesn't make the graph any larger, can only make it smaller

Any help would be appreciated
Here's a sample aov object if people want to do some testing `aov_obj = aov(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length*Sepal.Length, data = iris)`

Thanks

Comment: Use options `out.width` and `out.height`.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, `out.___` can't seem to make the plot bigger. It can make it smaller, but I can't get the graph to exceed its default size

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue